# Scripts returning double spaces to xhr request (ajax)

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, post, return

Something strange is happening since I moved my webserver to a new machine.

Now whenever an ajax call completes and nothing is returned, the data variable contains two spaces.

I have:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://192.168.0.6/access/login',
    data: 'user='+user+'&pass='+pass+'&rem='+remember,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data)
    {
                alert(data.length)
        if(data)
        {
            $('#errorMessage').html(data) ;
            $('#loginWarn').fadeIn() ;
        } else {
            window.location = 'login'
        }   
    }
})
```

On success my PHP script returns 0, indicating success and nothing is returned so the user is redirected to 'login'.

However, since the move 'data' is now a variable of length two (tested with data.length).

Does anyone know what is wrong?

Comment: `data: {user: user, pass: pass, rem: rem}` is the correct syntax. Can you check with this.

Comment: @ejo The string in my post is correct, this is not the problem as it worked fine before I moved it to a new webserver.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://192.168.0.6/access/login',
    data: '{ "user":"' + user+ '",pass":"' + pass+ '",rem":"' + remember+ '"}',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(data)
    {
                alert(data.length)
        if(data=="true")
        {
            $('#errorMessage').html(data) ;
            $('#loginWarn').fadeIn() ;
        } else {
            window.location = 'login'
        }   
    }
})
```

Comment: That causes my script not to function, it just takes POST variables. There was no problem with my script until I moved it to a new webserver.